# PHP show notification on page load

Tags: jquery

When I click on a button it shows an amazing notification at the top of the screen. Now I want to show this notification to the user as soon as he loads the page, but how can i do this?

This is the code of the button:

```
<span class="btn btn-success" data-layout="top" data-type="success" data-toggle="notyfy">Success</span>
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you mean alert? http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts

Comment: Just add an id to your span like `id="spanSuccess"`...and then, this piece of code should do the trick: `$(function(){ $('#spanSuccess').click(); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using `notyfy` jquery plugin. So you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  notyfy({text: 'notyfy - Yet another jQuery notification plugin'});
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works how I wanted it to be.
But how can I change the color of the notification to green? So it looks like a succes message. @adriancarriger

Comment: In the button you can find data-type="success", changing this also changes the layout of the notification, but the code from the fiddle always uses the white background.

Comment: Just add `type: 'success'` like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/adriancarriger/j0f4y4by/10/)

Comment: Ahh you are amazing! @adriancarriger